# Can't restore viewer'state while loading markups

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupCore extension to create markups then I store viewer'state and the svg string in my database. When I try to show the markups on a layer, the restoreState function doesn't seem to work . It just displays the markups with the current state of the viewer.
Here is the three lines of code:

```
markup.show();
markup.viewer.restoreState(viewerStatePersist);
markup.loadMarkups(markupsPersist, "layerName");
```

When I comment the first line (markup.show() ) I have the desired state without the markups.

Comment: I will add some instructions to this blog post - https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewing-large-ocrterrain-images-forge-viewer

which shows you how to load markup.  I add some example code on how to restore it.  Hold on

Comment: Hi ! thanks you in advance.

Comment: To serialize, use the 'var svgData = generateData()' command, and then restore the svgData back into the ForgeViewer using... 'loadMarkups(svgData,"mytestlayer") '
Details can be found in this link: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/markupscore/#loadmarkups-markupstring-layerid

Comment: Here is a blog article that explains how to persist and restore markup data:  https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension

Comment: also a tutorial... https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html

Comment: I created an example, walkthrough, of the process for creating, restoring both view state and some markup.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662806/when-the-2d-draw-read-the-saved-markup2d-the-draw-lost-color/53678051#53678051

Comment: Thanks for all this links.My problem was that I saved a wrong value of the viewer's state.

Comment: I faced the same problem. The viewer state I stored in the database is  'var viewerData = JSON.stringify(markup.viewer.getState());'. How do you save the viewer state?